# Adding external ssd to single node hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I have to add external ssd to my single node hadoop cluster and make use of that disk as datanode where my blocks will be stored.

I have a running apache single node hadoop cluster . But now requirements are that can we use it as another datanode directory and how??

Thanks in advance

Shakir

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may add it as a data-node. Install hadoop on the new node, setup passwordless ssh and copy the configuration to the new node.

Read this: [Steps to add a node in Hadoop cluster](https://www.quora.com/How-to-add-a-node-in-Hadoop-cluster/answer/Priyanka-753?srid=jgVe)

Comment: No its not what i meant...We can add external ssd to one of the node and mount it and then copy this mounted directory path to dfs,datanode.dir property..and restart the affected services from ambari webui.